# Haskell - problems with types

Tags: haskell, types

I've started learning Haskell and got problems. I try to understand lambda and created function `mo06`

```
mo06 f x = if f x
           then x
           else x * x
```

I can call that in ghci:

```
λ mo06 (== 1) 1
1
λ mo06 (== 1) 3
9
```

That works ok - no problems and no questions, but...

...I want to write my function as

```
mo08 f = fac (\x ->  if f x then x else x * x)
```

where

`fac` means factorial:

```
fac :: Num a => Int -> Int
fac n
  | n == 0    = 1
  | n > 0     = n * fac (n-1)
  | otherwise = error "fac only defined on natural numbers"
```

and call it as previously

```
mo08 (==1) 3
```

I try and got an error:

> Could't match expected type 'a -> a' with actual type 'Int'.

Changing `fac`  to `(fromIntegr fac)` did not help.

Thank you.

Comment: the `Num a` constraint on your `Int -> Int` function is meaningless; just remove it. alternatively, change from `Int -> Int` to `a -> a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to move `fac` one in:

```
mo08 f = \xx -> fac (if f (xx) then xx else xx * xx)
```

or (if you like)  move the `xx` to the left of the `=`:

```
mo08 f xx = fac $ if f (xx) then xx else xx * xx
```

to see why just look at `\xx -> ...` - this will be a function - here it will take an `Int` and produce an `Int` - same with `fac :: Int -> Int` - so when you try `fac (\xx -> ...)` you are actually trying to plug a function into `fac` (that is what the error is trying to tell you) - but if you move the `fac` inside the definition of the lambda it will work.

### using composition

of course maybe you tried to use function-composition:

```
mo08 f = fac . (\xx -> if f (xx) then xx else xx * xx)
```

but as you can see you need to use the composition operator `(.)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

That lambda expression (of type `a -> a`) is not an integer, yet in `mo08` you are trying to call `fac` on it - while `fac` expects an `int`. You will need to to put the `fac` call on the end result:

```
mo08 f = (\xx -> fac (if f xx then xx else xx * xx))
```

or alternatively use function composition:

```
mo08 f = fac . (\xx -> if f xx then xx else xx * xx)
```